# XPath to access an attribute value with a name that has special characters

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to access to attribute value, but the attribute name has special characters, for example:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1 at:it="true">W</ELEMENT1>------
    <ELEMENT2>IN</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1 acón='sys'>2</ELEMENT1>------
    <ELEMENT2>ARQ</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>MR</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>AC</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>3</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>I</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3 at:it="true" >RP</ELEMENT3>------
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>1</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>CC</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>XX</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4 eléct='false' >I</ELEMENT4>------
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>12</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2 at:it="true" >IN</ELEMENT2>------
    <ELEMENT3>3</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4></ELEMENT4>
  </row>
</root>
```

if I change the names of the attributes and remove them special characters, I can access them:

```
at:it ------> atit
Acón ------> Acon
eléctr ------> elect
```

but attribute names with special characters I can not access them with XPath query expression.

How I can access an XML file to values of attributes with names that have special characters?

To transform the XML file to DOM I used Java6, javax.xml.*, org.w3c.dom.*

Comment: Angel, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You've been here a few months, and asked 9 questions, but have yet to [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) or [**upvote**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) any answers.  Please read the linked pages and consider accepting and/or upvoting answers that have helped you.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that a colon (`:`) [***should***](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn) only be used in an element or attribute name if part of namespace prefix:

> **Note**:
>
> The Namespaces in XML Recommendation [[XML Names]](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#xml-names) assigns a meaning to
>   names containing colon characters. Therefore, authors should not use
>   the colon in XML names except for namespace purposes, but XML
>   processors must accept the colon as a name character.

So,

```
/root/row/ELEMENT1/@at:it
```

will work to select `"true"` *provided that you change your XML by defining the `at` namespace prefix in your XML (preferable)*,

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:at="http://example.com/at">
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1 at:it="true">W</ELEMENT1>------
    <ELEMENT2>IN</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1 acón='sys'>2</ELEMENT1>------
    <ELEMENT2>ARQ</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>MR</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>AC</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>3</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>I</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3 at:it="true" >RP</ELEMENT3>------
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>1</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>CC</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>XX</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4 eléct='false' >I</ELEMENT4>------
  </row>
  <row>
     <ELEMENT1>12</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2 at:it="true" >IN</ELEMENT2>------
    <ELEMENT3>3</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4></ELEMENT4>
  </row>
</root>
```

or instruct your XML processor to ignore XML namespaces (***not*** a best practice).

The next two cases are fine:

```
/root/row/ELEMENT1/@acón
```

will select `"sys"` without problem provided your XPath processor supports UTF-8 encoding (and it should).

```
/root/row/ELEMENT4/@eléct
```

will select `"false"` similarly.

Comment: thanks, I've tried with ... factory.setNamespaceAware (false); ... but still it does not work well ... I also tried with ... factory.setNamespaceAware (true); ... and xsi: it. ..but not work ..I will continue testing

Comment: As stated, you really should not use a colon in an element or attribute name unless it is part of a namespace prefix.  Although technically the spec allows it, I'm not surprised to hear you're having trouble.  Really, just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with Java 6 and had no problems to access attributes with accents. The colon is a special case, because it is used to denote element/attribute names with namespace prefixes. The XML doesn't use namespaces otherwise there were a namespace declaration for prefix `at`.

The XML parser has a switch to treat colons as part of the name but the XPath engine is always namespace aware. But with a little trick it is also possible:

```
File xmlFile = new File("in.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
// Parse without namespaces. Otherwise parsing leads to an error 
// because there is no namespace declaration for prefix 'at'.
factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();

XPathExpression expr1 = xpath.compile("/root/row/ELEMENT1/@acón");
//XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("/root/row/ELEMENT1/@at:it");  Doesn't work!
XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("/root/row/ELEMENT1/@*[name() = 'at:it']");
XPathExpression expr3 = xpath.compile("/root/row/ELEMENT4/@eléct");

System.out.println((String) expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
System.out.println((String) expr2.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
System.out.println((String) expr3.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING));
```

The output is:

```
sys
true
false
```

Comment: ...thanks,thanks, I had tried with...
factory.setNamespaceAware (false);....
but still it does not work fine

Answer (score 0):

1. first get the attributes from your nodes and then check their name.
2. Something like:
    `XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath(); NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(filteringExpression, xmlDocument,                         XPathConstants.NODESET);`
3. Then iterate through nodes and for each node get its attribute:
    `Node node = nodes.item(idx); NamedNodeMap nl = node.getAttributes();`
4. Then iterate through attributes and if the name matches ,get its value:
    `Attr attr = (Attr) nl.item(i); if(attr.getName().equals(...)) String attributeValue = attr.getValue();`